# inherited classes and razor asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Good morning, I have a problem with returning my database information (generated using the EF 6 code-first method) for my View Razor. The issue is that I'm wanting to return the information from inherited classes in the View, but they are not available, only the properties of the base class are presented, not those of the dependent classes.
The following are the Model, Controller, and View classes used:

Class ClientModel

```
public class Client
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone principal")]
    public string Phone1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone Alternativo")]
    public string Phone2 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrcamentoContato> Contacts { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Contrato> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

Class FisicModel

```
public class PessoaFisica : Client
{
    public TipoPessoa PersonType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nome completo*")]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "O campo é obrigatório.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RG { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo CPF é obrigatório.")]
    [StringLength(14)]
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Filiação")]
    public string Filiacao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Class JuridicModel

```
public class PessoaJuridica : Client
{
    public TipoPessoa PersonType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Razão Social*")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "O campo é obrigatório.")]
    public string SocialName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "CNPJ*")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "O campo é obrigatório.")]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Inscrição Estadual")]
    public string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Inscrição Municipal")]
    public string InscricaoMunicipal { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string ContactWith { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            var clients = db.Clients.ToList();

            return View(clients);
        }
```

Index View

```
    @model IEnumerable<CabinePhoto.Models.Entidades.Client>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Birth)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone2)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Birth)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone2)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

IdentityModel

```
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
public DbSet<PessoaFisica> PessoaFisica { get; set; }
public DbSet<PessoaJuridica> PessoaJuridica { get; set; }
```

All the information is stored in the same client table, since I'm using the form of inheritance by hierarchy, but in the view only the client model information is returned

Comment: Show full view definition.

Comment: Hi @Tanveer Badar, the code is:

Comment: Edit your question and paste it there.

Comment: What's more in the code is just the definition of the Model at the top of the file. All generated code was sent already in the image.
What is this:
@model IEnumerable <CabinePhoto.Models.Entidades.Client>

Comment: I think @TanveerBadar's point is one I'll make too. Never post code as images. It's basically useless at that point, and especially when trying to help you with sample code, it means we have to transcribe the code for you, which no one is going to want to do.

Comment: @Chris Pratt - Thanks for the considerations and I apologize for the pictures
I did the editing and put all the necessary code now. could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to solve the problem. I'll leave here recorded what I did to solve the problem in respect to inheritance.

First, I created a ViewModel and put two ICollection properties, I modified the controller by adding the queries referring to the client table, but specifically bringing the required types and finally, I passed the ViewModel to the Index.cshtml and I used two foreachs to retrieve the information from According to the type specified, shown below:

ClientesiewModel.cs

```
public class ClientesViewModel
{   
    public IEnumerable<PessoaFisica> Fisica { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PessoaJuridica> Juridica { get; set; }
}
```

controlle.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var cliente_fisico = db.Clientes.OfType<PessoaFisica>().ToList();
        var cliente_juridico = db.Clientes.OfType<PessoaJuridica>().ToList();
        var cliente = db.Clientes.ToList();

        ClientesViewModel clientes = new ClientesViewModel()
        {
            Fisica = cliente_fisico,
            Juridica = cliente_juridico
        };

        return View(clientes);
    }
```

View Index.cshtml

```
    @model CabinePhoto.ViewModels.ClientesViewModel

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Nome")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Telefone")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Telefone 2")
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @if (Model.Fisica != null || Model.Juridica != null)
    {
        foreach (var fisica in Model.Fisica)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => fisica.NomeCompleto)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => fisica.TelefonePrincipal)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => fisica.TelefoneAlternativo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = fisica.ClienteId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = fisica.ClienteId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = fisica.ClienteId })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        foreach (var juridica in Model.Juridica)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => juridica.PessoaContato)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => juridica.CNPJ)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => juridica.TelefonePrincipal)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = juridica.ClienteId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = juridica.ClienteId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = juridica.ClienteId })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Thanks for the help previously assigned

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a variable like this in your controller.

```
Client c = new Client();
```

If you later wrote

```
c.ClientId = 1;
```

it would work perfectly.

Similarly, if you wrote

```
PessoaFisica p = new PessoaFisica ();
```

and later

```
p.Name = "abc";
```

it would also work.

However, if you wrote

```
Client c = new PessoaFisica();
c.Name = "abc";
```

It will fail to compile.

Along the same lines

```
@model IEnumerable <CabinePhoto.Models.Entidades.Client>
```

means static type of your `Model` is a collection of `Client` objects, it will only allow you to bind to properties defined in `Client` class.

Comment: I understood. But in this case, I will retrieve the information from the database, from a single table, client, which has all the fields of the Client class and those that inherit this class. The problem is being in this, in returning this information to the list.

Comment: Correct, but IEnumerable<Client> neither knows nor cares about your database schema. It sees Client and shows only Client fields. I am not sure but you can try IEnumerable<dynamic> as your @model.

Comment: Okay, how can I pass this <dynamic>? Do you have any specific rules to use in the controller?

Comment: Update your view to say `@model IEnumerable<dynamic>` and see if it works. It will disable intellisense but may work at runtime.

Comment: When running the application with <dynamic>, the system generated these fields, which do not exist in my application:
Invalid column name 'BirthDate'.
Invalid column name 'Filiacao'.
Invalid column name 'TypePerson1'.
Invalid column name 'PersonContact'.
Invalid column name 'ClientIdentity'.
Invalid column name 'ClientId1'.

Comment: In fact, two of the fields exist, but those that are like '1' in the end, do not exist.

Comment: And it was pointed out that the error was in the controller in the query:
 Var client = db.Clients.ToList ();

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework actually returns the correct types, but you're effectively upcasting everything to `Client` by the variable type you're storing into and the model definition of the view. Essentially, you just need to cast to the right type. Unfortunately, there's no way to just *know* what type it should be after it's been upcasted. You'll have to conditionally check:

```
if (item is PessoaFisica)
{
    var pessoaFiscica = (PessoaFisica)item;
    // now you can access those derived typed properties off of `pessoaFiscica`
}
```

You can also use `as` and rely on the fact that it returns null when something can't be casted:

```
var pessoaFiscica = item as PessoaFisica;
if (pessoaFiscica != null)
{
    // access PessoaFiscica properties
}
```

With C# 7.0, you can use the pattern matching syntax to streamline it a little:

```
if (item is PessoaFiscica pessoaFiscica)
{
    // use `pessoaFiscica`
}
```

The pattern matching syntax also allows you use switch blocks, which may make things much easier on you:

```
switch (item)
{
    case PessoaFisica pessoaFisica:
        // do something with `PessoaFisica` instance
        break;
    case PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica:
        // do something with `PessoaJuridica` instance
        break;
    default:
        // do something with generic `Client` instance
        break;
}
```

Comment: Okay, but these conditions would be in View Index.cshtml? Or the controller?

Comment: Wherever you need to use the properties on the derived types instead of the base type, so yes, in this instance, you'd need to do that in your view, since that's where you're iterating over your list of `Client`s.

Comment: I tried to do it here with what you gave me and it did not work. I'm not sure I did it right. Could you simulate a small sample excerpt?